# How can I add my Bootstrap classes to a custom menu?

Tags: theming, navigation

How can I add different Bootstrap menus to [menu_tree_output()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/7.x)?

I know this is a very common question asked by a number of people earlier. I have found tons of answers, but none of them are working for me. However, I have tried a number snippets and here is the latest piece of code I am working on to get all menus and sub-menus.

```
<?php 
  $menuTree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
  $menu_tree_array = menu_tree_output($menuTree);
  print render($menu_tree_array);
?>
```

It works and prints all the submenus, however, It adds the same "menu" class to all parent ul. Rather I would like add sub-menu classes like the below output:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="http://example.com/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://example.com/biography/">Biography</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"> <!-- Like this. -->
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`theme_menu_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x). See the example [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/19004#comment-19004).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.